# wix: How to set environment variable based on UI radio-group value?

Tags: wix

In a Wix installer, I'm trying to set an environment variable based on the value of radio group. I'm not having luck finding out how to do it.

The radio group in the UI has 3 options:

1. Do not set environment variable
2. Set the variable per user
3. Set the variable per machine

The UI with the 3-button radio group looks like this:

```
<Control ...>
  <RadioButtonGroup Property="VAR_SCOPE">
    <RadioButton Value="user" ... />
    <RadioButton Value="machine" ... />
    <RadioButton Value="none" ... />
  </RadioButtonGroup>               
</Control>
```

The component that creates the environment variable is like this:

```
<Directory ...>
  <Component ...>
    <CreateFolder />
    <Environment Id='Evar' Action='set' System='yes' Name='FOO' Value='bar' />
  </Component>
</Directory>
```

Whether the env-var is set per user or per machine is dependent on the value of the 'System' attribute: yes for machine, no for user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe MSI supports this.  I see a comment in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368369(v=vs.85).aspx saying that on Windows 2000  the * prefix  controls scope but I've never used this.  As far as I know, MSI always respects the system context of the installation.  ( Per-User vs Per-Machine)  I suppose that is a short coming compared to what the registry table can do.   Environment variables are effectively just registry table entries  with a SendMessage  so you could use Registry and a minmilist custom action.

If you do this, you'd want to have 2 mutually exclusive components.

Comment: I'm just now learning Wix, so I don't know how to do many things. Usually, installers have one checkbox for adding/omitting changes to PATH variables. Can you show code to do something like that? Some kind of conditional way of modifying env variables.